# Displaying dirty cell triangle on grid when changing datasource manually

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with custom popup edit window to imitate popup edit, but with batch edit. Everything works fine, but I am experiencing a small issue. Whenever value is changed, the grid cell does not have that red triangle thingy in the corner indicating that this particular value different from original.

As I understand in this post, manually made changes in datasource does not appear on the grid, so I have to add them manually.

This post '[manually maintain dirty cell marker on paging in Kendo grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762959/manually-maintain-dirty-cell-marker-on-paging-in-kendo-grid)' gives an idea how to get it working. I could attach some listeners to kendoWindow inputs, track what fields are being edited, compare old and new values...

But is there a less painful way to achieve this functionality? Maybe there is some built in kendo function to achieve that?

Here's a small working example http://dojo.telerik.com/aSaXe/4

Answer (score 1):

The red "dirty" marks appear automatically **only** when the [built-in in-cell editing](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing) is used. From this point of view, your scenario requires these to be added manually after the custom editing popup is closed.

You may find the [`change`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model#events-change) event of the data item useful in the task. It will be fired each time a value in the popup is changed and the respective textbox is blurred.

```
var uid = $(e.target).parents('tr').attr('data-uid');
var grid = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid");
var dataItem = grid.dataSource.getByUid(uid);

dataItem.bind("change", function(args) {
  // args.field
});
```

Finally, keep in mind that each change in the Grid dataSource causes the whole table to be redrawn (unless the built-in in-cell editing is used), so you will lose any previously applied custom styling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the save event on your kendo grid as:

```
save: function (e) {
                    addDirtyUid(e.model.uid);
                    setTimeout(refreshVisualDirtyElements, 100);
                }
```

Other functions and var:

```
var dirtyIds = [];
function addDirtyUid(currentUid) {
    if (dirtyIds.indexOf(currentUid) === -1) {
        dirtyIds.push(currentUid);
    }
}

function refreshVisualDirtyElements() {
    for (var i = 0; i < dirtyIds.length; i++) {
        var thisUid = dirtyIds[i];
        $("tr[data-uid='" + thisUid + "']").find("td:eq(0)").addClass("k-dirty-cell");
        $("tr[data-uid='" + thisUid + "']").find("td:eq(0)").prepend('<span class="k-dirty"></span>');
    }
}
```